# Is it important to keep the sequence of a chained query(.find) in Mongoose?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I'm studying how to query with Mongoose.

I have a model called `statusModel`, and I constructed a query function:

```js
    const result = await statusModel
        .find(filter)
        .sort({ _id: 'desc' })
        .limit(limit)
        .exec()
    return { result, count: result.length }
```

Is the sequence of method chaining important?

I changed to add limit() right after the find() function, but the result was same as the upper code.

It seems like Mongoose conduct filtering first, sorting next, and then limitting the number of results no matter how I locate the query methods. Is it right?

Then, what should I do when I want to limit the number of results first and then conduct sorting of them?

Answer (score 0):

We can find the note in [**Limit**](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/drivers/node/current/fundamentals/crud/read-operations/limit/#limit) documentation of [node-mongodb-driver](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/drivers/node/current/):

> The order in which you call `limit` and `sort` does not matter because the driver reorders the calls to apply the sort first and the limit after it. The following two calls are equivalent:

```js
myColl.find(query).sort({ length: -1 }).limit(3);
myColl.find(query).limit(3).sort({ length: -1 });
```

Mongoose use [`node-mongodb-driver`](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/blob/7.3.1/package.json#L24) underly.

If you want to limit first, then sort after it, you can use the aggregation framework, like this:

```
const filter = {};
const r = await statusModel.aggregate().match(filter).limit(2).sort({ _id: 'desc' }).exec();
```

So we can limit the maximum number of records to pass to the next stage.